# Extracting primary and secondary roads from OpenStreetMap data

Tags: openstreetmap

After importing my country roads from OSM data, I need to create a network ( roads connecting big cities ) for use with pgRouting.

For this, I need the green, blue and red ones (http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=11/-29.8582/-51.5238) but I'm unsure how to select them in database, since OSM is not clear about how to find them.

I just try http://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/highway#values using PRIMARY and SECONDARY tag values, but the result sometimes gives me the orange and yellow ones too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As already mentioned you have to look at the [highway](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3ahighway) key.

The colors you are talking about are defined by the [rendering stylesheet](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Stylesheet) and represent the following [tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags):

- blue: highway=motorway, highway=motorway_link
- green: highway=trunk, highway=trunk_link
- red: highway=primary, highway=primary_link
- orange: highway=secondary, highway=secondary_link
- yellow: highway=tertiary, highway=tertiary_link

For more details on the colors refer to the [stylesheet of the current default layer](https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/blob/master/roads.mss) at [openstreetmap.org](http://www.openstreetmap.org). There is also a [description on the international equivalence](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Highway%3aInternational_equivalence) of these values.

Answer (score 3):

Use the OpenStreetMap (OSM) Key for Highways:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway

Answer (score 3):

It's true, what is in special interest in this case are all objects with highway=* tagged.

BUT usually all the processing is already done by [OSM2pgrouting](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgrouting) and you don't need to struggle around with tagging schemas etc.
If you then want to tweak the routing itself, you might consult the [pgrouting manual](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/doc/index.html).

So you download an [OSM planet extract](http://planet.osm.org/), (optional filter it for highway=* objects using osmosis) and drop it to osm2pgrouting.