# Finding Network Data for Route Optimisation in Saudi Arabia using ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data, route, optimization, saudi-arabia

I have to do a route optimisation through ArcGIS vrp solver for 1200 pizza drop points/daily, for a city based in Saudia Arabia.

Where can i get the road  network dataset?

Comment: Your question is about data, not routing. Please edit the title to make this clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `OSM`(OpenStreetMaps) road data, take a look at [How to extract primary and secondary roads from OSM data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78791/how-to-extract-primary-and-secondary-roads-from-osm-data) and also look at this [question from the OpenStreetMap Help](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/30692/export-only-roads) as well.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an OSM issue to me.

You can obtain the data for Saudi Arabia (GCC States) here e.g.: http://download.geofabrik.de/asia/gcc-states.html.

A close look at the data will be required, and if it fits for your application depends strongly on the mapping quality, but i did some routing application for germany with the related data and for me it worked great!

Additional hint for data processing: If you consider using open source thing for this, a blog post from Anita Graser is helpful: http://anitagraser.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/. Since ArcGIS 10.4 should access PostGIS, perhaps this worth a consideration.