# How to extract seamarks from OSM PBF?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, osmosis

Ref to this: http://forum.openseamap.org/viewtopic.php?id=2060 and this: [How to extract primary and secondary roads from OSM data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78791/how-to-extract-primary-and-secondary-roads-from-osm-data) and this: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Seamarks/Seamark_Objects

I need to import all seamarks from my OSM planet data to my PostgreSQL OSM database, but I can't find the "seamark:type=*" tag in osm2pgsql default.style file.

Can someone show me an example line to write into default style (or osmosis parameter) to import this kind of data to PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it:

```
osmosis --read-pbf south-america-latest.osm.pbf --tag-filter accept-nodes seamark:type=* --write-xml seamarks.osm
```